# Enforcing Auto Layout Constraints Across The View Hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, nsview, nslayoutconstraint

I have two buttons that I want to be kept the same size, but the problem is that they have two different parent views.  Autolayout seems to be ignoring the "equal size" constraint in this scenario. Constraining buttons with the same parent view works just fine.

I've created a very simple example that depicts what I am seeing:

[image: Constraints for One and Two]
[image: Constraints for Three]

As you can see from the above, buttons *Two* and *Three* are both set to have the same size constraint as button *One*. The only difference is that button *Three* is contained within another `NSView`.  There are no width constraints that are linking button *Three* and its containing view.

However, when I run and resize the window, it looks like:

[image: Running app]

It doesn't matter whether I use the Interface Builder layout, or do it in code using the `-[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]` method.

What am I missing? Is this not supported by Autolayout?  Thanks a lot.

**Edited:** Added screenshot to indicate button *Three*'s constraints.

Comment: Your constraints relating button Three to it's parent view must be taking priority. Can you detail them to us please? Btw how did you capture the animated gif?

Comment: I've added another screenshot indicating button Three's constraints.  And I used LiceCap (http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) to capture the animated gif.

Comment: gonna mess round with this. Will be in touch shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work OK. I set up an example project to do the same thing. I have three buttons with equal width constraints between button one and button two. Then the same between button two and button three. Button one has a trailing edge constraint relative to it's parent view.

[image]

Note that between the second and third button, Interface Builder didn't let me do this in the main window. Instead, I had to do it using the document list on the left.

The result can be seen below:

[image]

Here's the link to the project:

https://github.com/MaxMacleod/ThreeButtonConstraintTest1

Couple of caveats. First, this is an iOS rather than an OS X project (I'm an iOS guy!). However the principles should be the same. Secondly, this doesn't pinpoint the exact reason why your project isn't working. However, if you can compare what this sample project does against yours, we can figure it out. I'll then update this answer. Better still if you could make your project available, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Like you, IB wouldn't let me select the second and third views in the main window. I had to do using the left-hand nav.

I've downloaded your app and will have a good look through it today (thanks for taking the time).  I've also uploaded my app to https://github.com/edwardaux/EnforcingLayout

I'll report back here shortly.

Comment: had a look at your project and it looks fine! Basically the same as mine more or less. Maybe there are differences in the Auto Layout implementations after all OS X vs iOS. I'm going to try to find something in the official docs...

Comment: FYI, I've pushed a couple of new commits to my repo.  

The first of which (3d4ac05) dumps out some debugging info about the commits... it seems that even though Xcode is showing the third button's constraint in Interface Builder (both using the blue lines and also in the list of constraints), at runtime they aren't actually applied (I'm using `NSLog` to dump the runtime constraints).  The second commit (e21fffd) abandons using Interface Builder and adds the constraints programmatically and now it works.

Comment: pretty crazy. Looks to me that this is an issue with IB. Could try emailing some of the Apple bods that gave the WWDC presentations? Or maybe tweeting some Auto Layout gurus, e.g. Erica Sadun. Maybe even raise a radar request?